# Getting error while sorting a map by value

Tags: c++, sorting, debugging

Here is my code:

```
bool cmp(const pair< pair<char,int>,int> &a,const pair< pair<char,int>,int> &b){
        return a.second>b.second;
    }
```

I'm trying to sort the map by value.
I cant figure out how do i tackle this error.

> Error: no match for 'operator-'(...)

Comment: You **cannot** sort a map by value. That is not the function signature required by a map either.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] please. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a map sort by value C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098150/how-to-make-a-map-sort-by-value-c)

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into Boost.Bimap (sort one way, fast access the other way)